# Is this a correct sentence? "I often give in to her."

Tags: word-usage, idioms, phrasal-verbs

I'm the one studying English now.

My girlfriend and I like to watch movies, however, I like to watch action movies while she like to watch romantic movies. So we often have conflicting opinions on choosing movies. And so I might say,

> "I give in to her frequently".

I'm not sure whether this is right or not, what is the better expression.
Could you help?

Comment: That just sounds too sexual. I'd avoid such sentence anytime.

Comment: @RokKralj I'm having trouble reading the sentence that way.

Answer (score 6):

> I often give in to her.

is indeed a correct sentence, although you might want to consider:

> I often defer to her.

They both mean that you are letting the other person have their way. However, *give in* might be construed as weakness, or as a way to end a protracted argument, whereas *defer* might be interpreted more as being polite and gentlemanly.

Comment: So in the context of marriage or relationships, I think, "I give in to my wife/girlfriend" is the correct phrasing. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This I remember very well. I had searched Internet for one of my favorite songs of MJ, *Give In to Me*.

Anyway,

> [Give in](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/give-in_1) - to finally agree to what someone wants, after refusing for a period of time.

The example there-

> The government cannot be seen to give in to terrorists' demands.

Do I need to paint you a picture?